# Prometheus alert $value in text (description)

Tags: alert, prometheus

I am using a value(from the query) of CPU utilization for example in description (in Prometheus alert). So i got a critical message about 85% CPU util - which is more than 80% that is fine.  But then when the utilization is back to normal (under 80%) i am getting a RESOLVE message with for example 81%.  So there is no actual value from prometheus, i have no idea why. please advise..

Comment: Does your alert rule container a `for` property?

Comment: yes it has for: 1m  for example

Comment: Do you think, that i will got actual value without "for:" paramter ?  But i will get alert imediatelly when the load is high  (not if it is high for example 2m  consecutive) if i am not wrong ?